# Transition during remove element

Tags: angularjs, materialize

I am using angularjs and materialisedcss for designing my webpage.I am have series of cards which will be displayed using ng-repeat.When the user clicks on a a button(with id=btnConfirm) the card will be deleted from the view.The code is below

```html
<div class="row">
<div ng-repeat="elem in leaveRequests" id="{{'card-'+$index}}" style="transition: all linear 0.5s;">
   <div class="col s12 m6 l4">
    <div class="card  red darken-2" style="margin-top:20px;" id="haha" >
     <div class="card-content white-text ">
      <span class="card-title ">{{elem.num}}{{$index}}</span>
      <p>Leave applied from {{elem.startDate |date}} to {{elem.endDate |date}} pending for approval </p>
      <div>
      
             <a href="" style="display:inline-block" id="btnApproveReject"  class="activator" ng-click="setValue('Approve')"><div class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light activator "><i class="fa fa-check activator" aria-hidden="true"></i></div><span id="acceptRejectButton" class="activator">Approve</span></a> 
          
             <a href="" style="display:inline-block" id="btnApproveReject" class="activator" ng-click="setValue('Decline')"><div class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light red darken-2 activator  "><i class="fa fa-times activator" aria-hidden="true"></i></div><span id="acceptRejectButton" class="activator">Decline</span> </a>
          </div>
      </div>

    <div class="card-reveal">
     <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Sure?<i
      class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
     <p>Are You Sure To {{value}} the leave Request</p>
     <a href="" style="display:inline-block" id="btnConfirm" ng-click="applyOrRejectLeave(elem.leaveID,value,$index)"><div class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light  "><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></div><span id="confirmButton">YES</span></a> 
          
            <a href="" style="display:inline-block" id="btnReject" class="card-title" ><div class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light red darken-2 "><i class="fa fa-times " aria-hidden="true"></i></div><span id="confirmButton" class="card-title">Cancel</span> </a>
          
    </div>
   </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</div>
```

and controller

```js
app.controller("ApproverController", function($scope, $http,mysignum,myname) {
    //$scope.data = [{title: 'welcome hello'},{title: 'great testing'}];

    $http.get("rest/leave/ApproverList", {}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.leaveRequests = data;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("error");
    });
    
    $scope.setValue=function(status)
    {
     $scope.value=status;
    }
    
    $scope.trymadi=function(index)
    {
     var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#card-'+index ) );
     myEl.remove();
     
    }
    
    $scope.applyOrRejectLeave=function(leaveId,response,index)
    {
     console.log(leaveId+" "+response);
     $scope.test={};
     $scope.test.leaveId=leaveId;
     $scope.test.response=response;
     var jsonData=JSON.stringify($scope.test);
     console.log(jsonData);
     
     $http({
         url: "rest/leave/leaveResponse",
         method: "POST",
         data: jsonData,
         headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            if (data) {
             $scope.trymadi(index);
                 
            }
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("error from create leave");
        });
 
    }
});
```

This is working fine .But my questions are

1.Is it the preferred angular way to do it.If not how to do it.
2.If yes then how to apply transitions during the element removal because the element now is getting removed instantly without any transitions.How to go about this.

Please help,any help would be appreciated

Comment: http://jsbin.com/usaruce/3/embed?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

You can apply some animation with jquery

```
$target.hide('slow');
```

or

```
$target.hide('slow', function(){ $target.remove(); });
```

to run the animation, then remove it from DOM

Comment: is it preferred to use jquery with angular

Comment: Instead of using a whole library for just a small purpose , you can use jquery for this litte purpose if you are using jquery so.

Comment: i am mainly using angualarjs.Jquery has been added because its needed by materialisedcss.

Comment: So use jquery for this purpose, create id of divs dynamically by using $index and some text and pass the dynamic id of that div in remove function

Answer (score 0):

Use ngAnimate. Refer Below links. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations

http://theoinglis.github.io/ngAnimate.css/#/